# Changing fixed size array to vector

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, vector, calculated-columns

A given file contains pairs of . Then take a toss-up two-digit number (called X), and compute the win/loss amount. The win/loss rule is if the input number matches X, then it’s a win and the winning total is (amount * 70); otherwise, it’s a loss of (-amount).

> `For example: [ticket.txt] 
>     09 10 
>     13 15 
>     25 21`

If the toss-up number is 09, the win/loss amount of the ticket is (10 * 70 - 15 - 21 = 664)

If the toss-up number is 42, the win/loss amount of the ticket is (-10 - 15 - 21 = -46).

While reading file by arrays has a fixed size. What I mean is that what if the file `ticket.txt` doesn't have specific size. Can someone help me to change reading file by array to vector or something else doesn't have fixed size.

> `For example: [ticket.txt] 
>     09 10 
>     13 15 
>     25 21
>     .. ..`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int line1[100]; // array that can hold 100 numbers for 1st column
int line2[100]; // array that can hold 100 numbers for 2nd column
int main()
{
    int winNum, winAmount = 0, lostAmount = 0, result = 0;
    int num = 0; // num start at 0
    ifstream inFile; 
    inFile.open("Ticket.txt"); //open File
    if (inFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Fail to open the file" << endl;      
        return 1;
    }


    int myArray[3][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            inFile >> myArray[i][j];

    cout << "Numbers from File: " << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)   
        {
            cout << myArray[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";       
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the toss-up number: "; // enter the win number
    cin >> winNum;

    for(int i = 0; i< 3;i++)
    {
        if (myArray[i][0] == winNum) 
        {
            winAmount = myArray[i][1] * 70; //  number user choose = win number, winAmount = winAmount * 70 - lostAmount
        }
        else
        {
            lostAmount = lostAmount + myArray[i][1]; //number user choose != win number, the amount will be -lost amounts
        }
    }

    result = winAmount - lostAmount;
    cout << result;

    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of different ways to approach this problem.

One could make a `vector` of `vector`s

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> myArray;
```

but this is pretty wasteful. Only the inner dimension is variable in size, so a quick improvement is

```
std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> myArray;
```

Loading `myArray` can be pretty simple, depending on how much verification you want to include. Here it is with minimal verification:

```
int number,amount;
while (inFile >> number >> amount)
{
    myArray.push_back({number,amount});
}
```

This will loop until two `int`s can't be read, be it because of the end of the file or garbage in the file. It is also easily fooled by a file with the worn number of columns . Better approaches use `std::getline` to get whole lines and make sure exactly two valid numbers and nothing else is on each line.

The rest of your code is unchanged.

But there may be a better way to do this, Consider

a) The loss amount never changes. You can precompute it and eliminate the loop in the event of a loss.

b) Extending on that, you can eliminate part of the loop on a win. The loss amount contains the winning number use the loss amount minus the winning amount. In other words,

```
winnings = amount * 70 - (loss - amount)
```

Which is the same as

```
winnings = amount * 70 - loss + amount
```

or

```
winnings = amount * 71 - loss
```

So we can stop looking as soon as we find a win and only do one calculation.

c) We can eliminate any need for a look-up loop with a `std::map`.

Reading in the file into a `std::map` is similar:

```
std::map<int, int> myMap;

int number,amount;
int loss = 0;
while (inFile >> number >> amount)
{
    myMap[number] = amount; // map the amount to the number
    loss += amount;
}
```

and look-up is something like

```
int result = 0;
auto found = myMap.find(winNum); // look in the map for a number

if (found != myMap.end()) // number is in the map
{
    result = 71* found->second; // take the winnings plus one extra to counterbalance 
                                // number's addition to the losses 
}
result -= loss; //remove the loss
```

The calculation loop is completely eliminated and less code is almost always better. Code that's not there has zero bugs. Unless it not being there IS a bug, but that's a different problem.

Note: For small files this approach will be SLOWER. `std::map` has a much lower time complexity than iterating a `std::vector`, but each of those iterations it has to perform can be much more expensive.

[Documentation on `std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

[Documentation on `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

[Documentation on `std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)